# How to do calculations on values from different rows

Tags: sql, ignite

This is related to Apache IGNITE Database

I'd like do calculations on values from different rows, but have not found any solution so far.

There are 3 fields in DB:

| TimeStamp | MetricName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 10:00:00 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1000 |
| 2021-04-01 10:00:20 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1030 |
| 2021-04-01 10:00:40 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1035 |
| 2021-04-01 10:01:00 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1045 |

I'd like to subtract TimeStamp and Value of previous row to calculate average per sec. It HAS TO BE FLEXIBLE because TimeStamp frequency CAN BE CHANGED from 20 sec to 10 sec or to any.

The output should look like this:

1. TimeStDiff = current TimeStamp - previous TimeStamp
2. ValueDiff = current Value - previous Value
3. AvgPerSec = ValueDiff / TimeStDiff

| TimeStamp | MetricName | Value | TimeStDiff | ValueDiff | AvgPerSec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 10:00:00 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-04-01 10:00:20 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1030 | 20 | 30 | 1.5 |
| 2021-04-01 10:00:40 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1035 | 20 | 5 | 0.25 |
| 2021-04-01 10:01:00 | node_cpu_seconds_total | 1045 | 20 | 10 | 0.5 |

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Done :) I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate on `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY TimeStamp ASC` and then do this calculation for every row in a loop, in Java or other imperative language.

The distributed nature of Apache Ignite makes the concept of "previous" row different, and there's also no support for "window functions", so I doubt it is doable in plain SQL, except for simple cases such as two row queries.